# SOAP API: <faultcode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</faultcode>

Tags: soap-api, soap, authentication, xml

I'm trying to authenticate via the SOAP API. I ported my code form a python script that worked perfectly. When I try to implement in JS (Google App Script specifically), I get an "Unknown Server Error".

Here is my code:

```
function sfLogin(username, password){

  var url = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0";
  var request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'+
                    '<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"'+
                        'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'+
                        'xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                      '<env:Body>'+
                        '<n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">'+
                          '<n1:username>'+username+'</n1:username>'+
                          '<n1:password>'+password+'</n1:password>'+
                        '</n1:login>'+
                      '</env:Body>'+
                    '</env:Envelope>';

  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8", 
    "SOAPAction": "login"
  }

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'headers': headers,
    'payload': request,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }
  try{
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  }
  catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);
  }   
}
```

Here is the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:sf="urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</faultcode>    
            <faultstring>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Element type &quot;env:Envelope&quot; must be followed by either attribute specifications, &quot;&gt;&quot; or &quot;/&gt;&quot;.
             </faultstring>
             <detail>
                <sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault">
                    <sf:exceptionCode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</sf:exceptionCode>
                    <sf:exceptionMessage>Element type &quot;env:Envelope&quot; must be followed by either attribute specifications, &quot;&gt;&quot; or &quot;/&gt;&quot;.
                    </sf:exceptionMessage>
                </sf:UnexpectedErrorFault>
             </detail>
          </soapenv:Fault>
      </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is my POST Option:

```
{
  headers={
    SOAPAction=login, 
    Content-Type=text/xml; charset=UTF-8
  }, 
  method=post, 
  payload=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
          <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
              <env:Body>
                 <n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
                <n1:username>MYUSERNAME</n1:username>
                <n1:password>MYPWORD</n1:password>
                </n1:login>
              </env:Body>
          </env:Envelope>, 
  muteHttpExceptions=true
}
```

I've retyped each letter of that request at least 10 times. It works perfectly in my python script, just not here...

Thank you

EDIT** I checked to see the outgoing request. Below is the payload being sent out:

```
payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
      <n1:username>USERNAME</n1:username>
      <n1:password>PASSWORD</n1:password>
    </n1:login>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I believe this looks fine.

Here are the headers:

```
{
  SOAPAction=login, 
  X-Forwarded-For=71.183.26.223, 
  Content-Type=text/xml; charset=UTF-8
}
```

URL is:

```
"https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/30.0";
```

Are there any obvious errors here that I'm missing?

EDIT2**: This just got a bit more strange. I figured that the ' or '/>'). I tried putting the whole element on a single line:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

This still gave the unknown error. But if I put a space between the xmlns and the preceding section, like so:

```
...XMLSchema" xmlns:...
```

I then get another error telling me the request must be of type xml/text (which it is and is put in the headers):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

soapenv:Client
content-type of the request should be text/xml

So maybe there is something to adding white space and new lines.. How should I be formatting this in JS?

Comment: Are there any logging tools you can use to see the actual outbound POST request? I'm wondering if the UrlFetchApp.fetch call is escaping the payload in some way?

Comment: That's a good call. I'll check

Comment: Another thought would be adding some white space between Envelope namespaces. Maybe add some newline characters in there for good measure, like after the XML declaration.

Comment: I've checked the request and posted the results above. They look good to me. I've never had a whitespace issue before - as long as the brackets are in place, shouldn't whitespace/newlines not matter?

Comment: Actually, with the new edit above, whitespace may be playing a role here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my earlier comments:

Make sure there is a whitespace between the namespaces on the `Envelope` element.

```
 <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="...
```

Also, try adding some newlines after certain parts of the SOAP message, especially after the XML Declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with both whitespaces AND with the google app script URLFetchApp.

The spaces were needed in the XML, so that instead of the envelope looking like:

It had the spaces:

Furthermore, although I put "text/xml" in the headers that were included in the request, google apps script automatically added contentType = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

You have to change the default options in the outgoing request rather than just adding content-type to the headers.

@DanielBallinger, both your suspicions turned out to be correct! Thank you!